# What is a good output format to combind multiple similar plots in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, facet-wrap, facet-grid

Let's say I have 100 variables column and 1 label column. The label is categorical, for example, 1,2,and 3. Now for each variable I would like to generate a plot for each category(e.g. boxplot). Is there a good format to show all plot? By using facet_grid, it seems that we can only put 16 plots together, otherwise the plot will be too small.

**Example code:**

```
label = sample.int(3, 50, replace = TRUE)
var = as.matrix(matrix(rnorm(5000),50,100))
data = as.data.frame(cbind(var,label))
```

Comment: I mean, you can still increase the size of the plots, and it will by default make it easier to include more plots. I'm not sure this question is clear enough. What about using multiple plots instead, i.e. 5 with each 10 plots

Comment: Have a look at `Rmarkdown` documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, if you want a box for each of 3 groups for each column of your data, then you would need 300 boxes in total. This seems like a bad idea from a data visualisation perspective. A plot should allow your data to tell a story, but the only story a plot like that could show is "I can make a very crowded plot". In terms of getting it to look nice, you would need a lot of room to plot this, so if it were on a large poster it might work.

To fit it all in to a single page with minimal room taken up by axis annotations, you could do something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(data, -label) %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(sub('V', '', name))) %>%
  mutate(row = (name - 1) %/% 20,
         label = factor(label)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(name), value, fill = label)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(row~., nrow = 5, scales = 'free_x') +
  labs(x = "data frame column") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

But this is still far from ideal.

An alternative, depending on the nature of your data columns, would be to plot the column number as a continuous variable. That way, you can represent the distribution in each column via its density, allowing for a heatmap-type plot which might actually convey your data's story better:

```r
pivot_longer(data, -label) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(sub('V', '', name))) %>%
  mutate(label = factor(label)) %>%
  group_by(x, label) %>%
  summarize(y = density(value, from = -6, to = 6)$x, 
            z = density(value, from = -6, to = 6)$y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = label, alpha = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  labs(x = 'data frame column', y = 'value', alpha = 'density') +
  facet_grid(label~.) +
  guides(fill = 'none') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask what does **row~.** mean in the line of **facet_wrap()**? Thanks

Comment: It is the formula notation for facet_wrap. The columns on the left of the tilde are put into rows, and those on the right into columns. Since there is only a dot on the right, there are no columns created. The `row` variable was created in the pipe near the start of the code purely as a faceting variable.